# Internet Explorer 10 does not remember cookies after restarting (or letting IE be closed in memory)

Tags: internet-explorer

I have read that Internet Explorer 10 for Windows Phone 8 has isolated/sandboxed tabs. Meaning that each tab should work independently of each-other.

I have set my settings to Accept all cookies.

Unfortunately, the cookies that are set only last until I close the program completely. Either by restarting the device or opening so many other applications that it is released from memory.

This is very inconvenient as I have to repeatedly reset settings and reauthenticate on my favorite web sites.

Is there any way to actually keep cookies persistently?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem IE is programmed to do so. It might be fixed in a later update. For now you could try downloading another browser from the marketplace.

Comment: There is no other browser. The few that are in the marketplace are just wrappers around IE with no functional difference.

Comment: UC Browser seems to allow some pop ups but I've heard about some security issues with them.