# Saving passwords in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: 8.0, internet-explorer, security, password

Since Internet Explorer 10 [cannot reliably store persistent cookies](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/1255/721), the fact that it does not have a password manager becomes more pressing.

Does anyone have any good solution for dealing with keeping track of all passwords and logins?

Good security policies include not using the same password on multiple sites. This makes it, unfortunately, rather difficult to remember all your different passwords. This is where a password manager comes in.

I see there is a [LastPass application](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/lastpass/9b86eadc-16e8-df11-9264-00237de2db9e), but I do not use their services. I would prefer not sharing my passwords with any third-party.

Comment: That link for lastPass doesn't work for me?

Answer (score 1):

There are a large number of password manager applications on windows phone. I use LastPass, because I do want to store passwords across devices and am happy with them on the desktop.

If you do want to share your passwords but not on their server, you may be more interested in the  [KeepPass client](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/7pass-free/7ab58ba1-f035-e011-854c-00237de2db9e), which lets you create your own database and store it on your own server/dropbox.

Or if you don't want any sharing at all, then I would probably go with something like Adam Nathan's app [Passwords and Secrets](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/passwords-secrets/11c2186b-4107-e011-9264-00237de2db9e), for which you can get the source code in his book, or any similar app that does not request access to data services - I also found [this one](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/secret-keeper/52d9be34-5497-e011-986b-78e7d1fa76f8), try searching for 'password' or 'secret'.

Answer (score 1):

I use and would recommend LastPass, but don't go on my word alone. Steve Gibson a security researcher did an [in-depth review](http://twit.tv/sn256) of LastPass technology and explains in easy to understand terms why you can trust them. A shorter text-based explantion can be found on the [LastPass Blog](http://blog.lastpass.com/2010/07/lastpass-gets-green-light-from-security.html) that references Steve's work.

They do not ever know what your passwords are. All encryption and decryption happens on your computer.

The sensitive data that is harbored on their servers is always encrypted before it’s sent to them, so all they receive is gibberish. Your Master Password encrypts all of your other passwords and cannot be deciphered by them.

They never receive the key to decrypt that data. This gives the added bonus of LastPass not being able to give your passwords up to any one for any reason (including legal government requests).

One downside is to enable the free app to work your last pass account must be paid. However this is $1/month or $12 a year. Fairly inexpensive for what they offer.

I hope you can take the time to listen to the podcast at the supplied link. It should address any concern you have with their technology and practices.